# EDX : How to set default advanced components for newly created course

Tags: edx, openedx

I have created a xblock, now I want to set this xblock as default xblock as an advanced component for every newly created course automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Does my proposed solution solve your problem?

Comment: Hay, unfortunately not worked,
I have found another solution for the same

Answer (score 3):

the right way to solve this problem is to edit the `CourseFields` class under `common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/course_module.py` file. You will find that there is a class variable called `advanced_modules` with type `List`. you can just do something like this

```
advanced_modules = List(
    display_name=_("Advanced Module List"),
    default=[], # this is where you add default values 
    help=_("Enter the names of the advanced components to use in your course."),
    scope=Scope.settings
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your XBlock to the list of advanced components. In your CMS settings file, add:

```
ADVANCED_COMPONENT_TYPES.append('your_xblock')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setup default advanced component**

edit the following file

```
cms/djangoapps/contentstore/views/components.py
```

Add the following line to function ‘get_component_templates()’
After

```
if isinstance(course_advanced_keys, list):
```

Add

```
course_advanced_keys.append('your_xblock')
```